# Difference between multiplying with print and with for loop

Tags: python, printing

The exercise is:

> Make a list of the first 10 cubes (that is, the cube of each integer from 1 through 10), and use a for loop to print out the value of each cube.

What is the difference when I write like this? I wrote this way:

```
numbers = list (range(1,11))
for number in numbers :

    print(number**3)
```

And a solution is:

```
cubes = []
for number in range(1, 11):
    cube = number**3
    cubes.append(cube)

for cube in cubes:
    print(cube)
```

Answer (score 5):

In your solution you are not making a list of the cube, you are just printing the cubes.